# Как в проект SAS добавить JAVA?

Tags: sas

Добрый день. Как в проект SAS добавить JAVA?
В разделе поддержки упоминают эту возможность, а папках с установленным SAS есть папка `SASPrivateJavaRuntimeEnvironment`. Но не могу найти инфу, куда нужно писать java-код..

Comment: Здравствуйте. Использовал Java в [следующем](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41953244/creating-internal-accounts-in-sas-metadata-server-by-programm-on-sas-base) кейсе.

Answer (score 2):

Файл Example1.java:

```
public class Example1 {
 public Example1 () {}
 public String getMessage () {return "Hello SAS";}
}
```

Вызов из sas кода:

```
data _null_;
 length message $200;
 declare javaobj j ('Example1');
 j.callStringMethod ('getMessage', message);
 j.delete();
put message=;
run;
```

```
message=Hello SAS
```

Подробнее можно почитать [тут](https://support.sas.com/resources/papers/proceedings/proceedings/sugi29/033-29.pdf)